# Button is changing by 2 other buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to use jQuery in my code. I'm beginner. I tried to do this with function ".replaceWith()".
I tried first to change the color to red. 
What I did:
http://jsfiddle.net/kzVSt/300/

```js
$(document).ready(){
   $("#del").click(function(){
       $("#del").replaceWith("<input type='button' id='del1' value='dsjkdsa'>");
   }); 
};
```

```css
#del1{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="del" value="button">
```

Comment: Snippet that works: http://jsfiddle.net/kzVSt/301/

Comment: FYI: in your HTML The button ID is "del", but in your CSS you have it as "del1"

Comment: That's because that CSS rule is for the new element he is inserting with Javascript

Comment: @AndreaJessup In the jQuery code it’s `del1`.

Comment: @Xufox *something something I'm too cooooool to read the code before having opinions* .... oops :)

Comment: @AndreaJessup This happens to me as well… too often…

Comment: It was because I make a mistake in document.ready definition ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#del").click(function(){
       $("#del").replaceWith("<input type='button' id='del1' value='dsjkdsa'>");
   }); 
});
```

```css
#del1{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="del" value="button">
```

Comment: Oh God, I don't remeber about 'function'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the [`ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // …
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using ID's and Classes incorrectly. Here's a couple tips

instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

alias it to

```
jQuery(function($){
```

This is a shortcode jQuery Alias to $ .ready() handler.

Next, if you replace the element with another element, all events bound to that element will be destroyed. Instead, toggle the class.

If you want to update the value, target the `.val()` method on the jQuery object (you can reference elements inside of their event by `$(this)`.

Lastly, use classes when you want to add some CSS colors, instead of changing the ID.

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#del').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('color-red');
        $(this).val('dsjkdsa');
    });
});
```